# Using DB without modifying it - Django

Tags: django

I need to connect to a Postgresql server in my Django project. But I'm under strict instructions NOT to make any modifications to the database or tables.

If I'm not wrong, simply adding this DB to `settings.py` and running `syncdb` would create and add some django specific tables to the database.

How can I get around this issue? If I add another (local) sqlite DB to `settings.py` under default and my remote postresql server separately; can I be sure of Django not creating any tables in my server? I couldn't find this info in the documentation.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Configure two databases in `settings.py`, and a create [database router](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/) to route your queries to the appropriate database.

Route all the Django admin / users stuff to your sqlite database (make it the `default` database, and make sure that is indeed the one your router returns by default), and single out your application queries that need to go to the Postgres database.

Routers also have a method to locate a DB for writes and one for reads, so you can use this as a failsafe: just make sure `db_for_write` never returns your Postgres database, and you're good to go.